# Can you use an 'In' operator in a column expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, calculated-columns

Using Oracle 11.  Trying to write some simple code for a conceptual demo. To illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, imagine I have `SOMETABLE` that has two columns: ID and NAME, like so:

```
ID  NAME
---------
1   Tom
2   Larry
3   David
4   Steve
```

I'm trying to compute a third column that is true if the second column matches one of two hard-coded values.  Something like this (which of course doesn't work.)

```
Select ID,
       NAME,
       (NAME in ('Larry', 'David')) as IS_FAVORITE
from SOMETABLE
```

and hoping to get this output...

```
ID  NAME   IS_FAVORITE
----------------------
1   Tom    FALSE
2   Larry  True
3   David  True
4   Steve  FALSE
```

Much to my surprise, I'm being told Oracle doesn't have the concept of booleans and I should be using 'numeric strings' or something like that, so this too is fine...

```
ID  NAME   IS_FAVORITE
----------------------
1   Tom    'N'
2   Larry  'Y'
3   David  'Y'
4   Steve  'N'
```

So can you use the `IN` operator in a column expression like this? If not, how would one compute the column that I am after?

Comment: `IN` is a condition, not a function. (It is not a function because Oracle doesn't have the Boolean data type; but it does have conditions. You just can't **return** the (Boolean) value of a condition for further processing.)

Comment: Yeah, figured that out by the below answer which worked like a champ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your expected output using `case` expression.

```
Select ID,
       NAME,
       CASE
        WHEN
            NAME in ('Larry', 'David')
        THEN
            'TRUE'
        ELSE
            'FALSE'
        END as IS_FAVORITE
from SOMETABLE
```

Comment: Oracle will complain that `FALSE` (and `TRUE` for that matter, but it will complain about `FALSE` first) are unknown identifiers.

Comment: Perfect!  Verbose, but perfect! (BTW, Oracle doesn't know what TRUE and FALSE are so I changed it to 'Y' and 'N')

Comment: What you used is a `case` **expression**. PL/SQL also has `case` **statements** (similar to, but different in their nature from, `case` expressions). There are no `case` *statements* in plain SQL.

Comment: Um... I'm confused.  @mathguy said you actually used a case expression, and you originally had 'expression' in the text, but just updated it to 'statement' even though he said SQL doesn't have a statement. Huh?? [scratching head]